# Distinguish theme (background) color for negative and positive values in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

For data of this type:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Q = c(rep("q_pol",10), rep("q_wh",10)),
  slope = c(rnorm(10,-0.5), rnorm(10, 0.5)),
  Recipient = rep(c("A", "B"),10)
)
```

how can I color the theme (or background) of these boxplots in two different colors: the upper half **for values > 0**, say, **"lightblue"** and the lower half **for values < 0**, say, **"darkblue"**:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = Q, y = slope, color = Recipient)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add different filled backgrounds using `geom_rect`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = Q, y = slope, color = Recipient)) + 
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(
    xmin = c(-Inf, -Inf),
    xmax = c(Inf, Inf),
    ymin = c(-Inf, 0),
    ymax = c(0, Inf),
    fill = c("darkblue", "lightblue")
  ), aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill), inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkblue" = "darkblue", "lightblue" = "lightblue"), guide = "none") +
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)
```

[image]